# New area results in 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

I've read every thread/question on this topic but never found an answer.

In my MVC4 project I've just added a new area called "Admin". I see that `AdminAreaRegistration.vb` has been generated by default:

```vb
Public Class AdminAreaRegistration
    Inherits AreaRegistration

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property AreaName() As String
        Get
            Return "Admin"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Sub RegisterArea(ByVal context As System.Web.Mvc.AreaRegistrationContext)
        context.MapRoute( _
            "Admin_default", _
           "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
    End Sub
End Class
```

I created an "AdminController" and an appropriate view and built the project.
Trying to navigate to

`/Admin`

`/Admin/Admin`

`/Admin/Admin/Index`

All ends in failure

[image: Generic 404]

I tried deleting the Admin area and created a new one called `Dashboard` with an `Admin` controller.

[image: Folder structure]

I also modified my MapRoute

```vb
context.MapRoute( _
    "Dashboard_default", _
    "Dashboard/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
    New With {.controller = "Admin", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
)
```

I tried every combination of namespace for `DashboardAreaRegistration`

`Namespace Areas`

`Namespace Areas.Dashboard`

`Namespace Dashboard`

I tried every combination of namespace for `AdminController`

`Namespace Areas`

`Namespace Areas.Dashboard`

`Namespace Areas.Controllers`

`Namespace Areas.Dashboard.Controllers`

I also tried including the namespace in `\App_Start\RouteConfig.vb`

`Imports Areas`

`Imports Areas.Dashboard`

`Imports Areas.Dashboard.Controllers`

No change, just 404. What can I do?

Comment: "created a new one called Dashboard with an Admin controller" - and when you tried `/dashboard/admin` you're getting 404?

Comment: Yeah. Tried `/Dashboard`, `/Dashboard/Admin`, `/Dashboard/Admin/Index`

Comment: I faced the same problem before. I just set `<identity impersonate="true" />` then the error went away.

Comment: Are you recompiling your application after making these changes?

Comment: @Tommy Yeah I've even tried doing App Pool recycles, server restarts and cleans/rebuilds.

Comment: In your main global.asax, do you have a call to AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() in your Application_Start() or equivalent?

Comment: I do. `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` is located in `Sub Application_Start()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days I finally resolved this issue, and **I have no idea why this worked**.

In my main `Web.config` I found

```
<section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />
```

This is line for Glimpse - a NuGet package that I installed to try to help resolve my problem in the first place. One of its features is assisting with routing debugging. *Note that the problem occurred exactly the same before and after I installed Glimpse; so I don't think it's related.*

1. I deleted this line
2. Saved `Web.config`
3. Refreshed my browser, I got an error (500)
4. Put the line back in
5. Saved again
6. Refreshed the page again, everything worked; I can access `/Dashboard`

Some sort of glitch or corruption?